# Can you confirm that my IP address was a Tor relay a few months ago?

Tags: relays, exit-relays

Let's assume I received a letter today that accuses me of downloading an illegal file, posting something inappropriate in a forum, or hacking into a system.  And that happened a few months ago.  But I was running a Tor relay on the IP address stated in the letter back then.  How can I prove that?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [ExoneraTor](https://metrics.torproject.org/exonerator.html), a tool by Tor Project designed for that work.

Of course you should also contact a lawyer with some affinity on Internet laws so as to handle better your case. If you're located in USA you could contact [EFF](http://eff.org/), a non-profit which actively and legally supports digital rights. If you're in Europe, people of [Torservers](https://www.torservers.net/) could give you some advice although they're not lawyers.

Comment: If necessary and/or required, the Tor Project can write a statement for you confirming that relay x was a part of the Tor network at time y.